# Stacking customization projects - screen enhancement

Tags: acumatica

I'm running into a situation for a specific deployment where the site has multiple ISV products as well as their own enhancements all to the same screen (In this case, Stock Item Maintenance)

All the items compile and function but the overall screen layout is correct.  Fields are shown either with the incorrect column spans or in the wrong position on the screen or not shown at all.   In this case, I'm referring to Form layouts, not grid based layouts.

Reordering the levels of the projects simply results in different screen layout issues.

Obviously one scenario is to merge the customization projects and clean up the resulting layout however with the ISV products being frequently updated that poses several other issues that we'd have to convince the customer and ISV to deal with.

While the "levels" allow the projects to publish and Extensions on Extensions allow fluent business logic flow, I have yet to see a good solution to stacking customizations.  What I'm ultimately looking to see if it is  possible to do something like this scenario:

1. Customization Project "A" published
2. Customization Project "B" rebased and modified post Project "A" layout
3. Customization Project "A" and "B" published
4. Repeated for Project "C" - "Z"

With the end result of the screen layouts looking exactly how we need based on all the above items.   This would be almost a "virtual" merge.

The other question is, what is being done at other locations when multiple ISV's are involved all touching the same screens.

Comment: The grid column layout is managed by the Columns Configuration popup window. After publishing an extension that alters grid column size and position, I go into Columns Configuration and press Reset To Default. https://help.acumatica.com/Wiki/ShowWiki.aspx?pageid=7dfe20fd-aa33-4ee2-9106-249bc856b455

Comment: The behavior can't be perfect because there's a conflict between User choices previously saved in Columns Configuration and the Programmer choices made in the customizations. That's why I go for a reset after publishing, that should select the Programmer choices. From there User can apply their changes and save Columns Configuration.

Comment: Right.   In this case I'm referring to form modifications, not grid based.   The grids are easy enough to fix by simply changing the order on the grid.